# How do I open an existing workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use my function in new workbook, the function is using datas from an old Workbook, where was written.

My function in new workbook is working correctly only, if the old workbook is open too. Otherwise result is #Value.

My code is:

```
Function findfix(EAN,year, As Variant)

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\dokumenty\NPU\NPUfix.xlsm")
ThisWorkbook.Activate

rowPos = findEAN(EAN)

c = Workbooks("NPUfix").Sheets("EAN").Cells(rowPos, 18).Value
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the function and related code into a new module, in the new workbook

Then just change `("H:\dokumenty\NPU\NPUfix.xlsm")` to your new location.

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If
'   Create the argument
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
  Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Then to get the value required

```
Sub TestGetValue()
    p = "c:\XLFiles\Budget"
    f = "Budget.xls"
    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"
    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you,
but I need to use data from the old workbook to get a result. And I would like to use the same function for more than 10 new workbooks, I'm not sure if copy paste method, it's the right way.

Comment: This make more sense now. your use of `*old* confused me. Please see edit